# Duplicate Key in Repeater error when there is no item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How to solve this error in angularjs? imagine I'm doing a todolist app, but my app crashes when there is no item in ng-repeat.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in myItems"></li>
```

I think it's because of myItems, which is a ajax returned object.

when the database doesn't have any value, the ng-repeat seem doesn't work and break the whole app

Comment: there is a missing `"` : should be `"item in myItems"`

Comment: are you sure you return a `valid json` from server when there is no item ?

Comment: what should I return?

Comment: if your `myItems` is an array, you should return `[]` when there is no item

Comment: how to check if callback is empty

Comment: I guess your problem is: when there is no item, you return an object instead of an empty array. You could debug or use network capture built-into browser to see what you get from server

Comment: Undefined variable: jsonData

Comment: try returning `[]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try, `<li ng-repeat="item in myItems"></li>` :)

May be, you are missed `"`

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error as Artyom said.

To solve Duplication error inside ng-repeat you can use **track by** as below:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in myItems track by $index">
```

Initialize myItems as below:

```
$scope.myItems={};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize myItems in controller

```
$scope.myItems={};
```